# Redefine two-dimensional array without malloc

Tags: arrays, c

I'm trying to recode some old code that was like:

```
//1 for vertical, 0 for horizontal
#define ORIENT 0 
#if (ORIENT == 0)
#define TX 10
#define TY 20
#else
#define TX 20
#define TY 10
#endif
uint8_t some_array[TX][TY]
```

Now I have a variable that indicates orientation which means I can't use defines. I also can't use mallocs.

First I defined tx and ty variables and replaced TX and TY everywhere except in the definition of some_array:

```
uint8_t tx = 10;
uint8_t ty = 20;
void init(){
    if(is_vertical){
        tx = 20;
        ty = 10;
    }
}
```

This works well but I still haven't solved my array problem.

I tried using some_array as it is, because I thought "it takes up 200 bytes anyhow" but it doesn't work.
I tried with redefining some_array as a uint8_t** and pointing to an array of 200 bytes, but it didn't work.

some_array is used in multiple places in the code, so I don't want to change it. I'm also limited with RAM (embedded programming) so I can't really define bigger then necessary arrays.

Any kind of solution where the remaining code can call some_array as `some_array[i][j]` is good enough

Comment: Use a plain 1D array and index it such as `array[y*tx + x]`

Comment: @EugeneSh. Hmmm I thought of it, but I would have to change the rest of the code, which I'm trying to avoid...

Comment: There are several solutions but _all_ of them will require a global edit of `some_array[i][j]` in each file and use. Or, adding a definition line to each function, so, again a global edit.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to avoid editing the access to `some_array[i][j]`

Comment: @EugeneSh. Please post this as answer so I can accept it, I did have to change code a bit but it didn't hurt too much and it works perfectly. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

There are a few solutions, but all require a global edit.

---

The macro solution:

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define TX      10
#define TY      20

uint8_t global_array[TX * TY];

int tx;
int ty;

#define some_array(i,j)             global_array[((i) * tx) + (j)]

void
func(void)
{

    some_array(3,7) = 0xFF;
}
```

---

Here is a macro and pointer solution:

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define TX      10
#define TY      20

uint8_t global_array[TX * TY];

int tx;
int ty;

#define SOME_DEF \
    uint8_t (*some_array)[tx] = (void *) global_array

void
func(void)
{
    SOME_DEF;

    some_array[3][7] = 0xFF;
}
```

Comment: consider casting to `void*` to avoid `__typeof__`

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but I've went with Eugens solution as it meant little code change.

Comment: @InvaderZim Fair enough. My macro solution _is_ the 1D solution [which is the most common] where the macro is syntactic sugar. It's arguably easier to convert `arr[y][x]` into `arr(y,x)` than `arr[((y) * tx) + (x)]`. And, easier to examine/maintain.